# Why is UISwitch only visible if I rename the class?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, uiswitch

I had a class called *OptionsTableViewController* which inherited **UITableViewController**. I changed the superclass to **UIViewController** implementing the *UITableViewDelegate* and *UITableViewDataSource* protocols, because I needed the tableView to be in a specific position.

Now some table cells have a **UISwitch** as accessoryView. The switch is an instance variable, initialized With *CGRectZero*.

When changing the superclass to **UIViewController** the switches are not shown. But when I also rename the class (to *OptionsViewController* f. e.) it works.

Does anybody know where this strange behavior comes from?
I also tried to clean the project and I even deleted the build folder - but it seems, that the only solution is to rename the class.

I had a similar problem before, where the whole table view would not be shown unless the class was renamed.

Comment: Are you sure the `accessoryView` has been set properly? Can you successfully log all accessory views to see if they are really set? It really can't be because of the class it's name, there should be *something* wrong *somewhere*.

Comment: This is how i set the accessoryView:  
  
    `cell.accessoryView = _switch;`
  
  
where the switch is an instance variable initialiazed as follows:  
  
    `_switch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];`
  
  
What do you mean by logging accessory views? I set a brakepoint and the application stopped at this point. So the command is executed for sure. 

I also tried to just add a switch as subview to the view (not the tableview) but this also wouldn't work. I assume, that the name of the class is used somewhere in the project, but not in the code I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for this problem. Although searching through the project XCode wouldn't find any files named OptionsTableViewController, but I found it included under Targets -> AppName. The file wouldn't disappear after Clean All Targets, so it is good to know that there still remain parts in there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to see if the names OptionsTableViewController and OptionsViewController are used anywhere else in your entire project, including in Interface builder nib files?  Did you change all the names, as appropriate?

Comment: I used the _Refactor..._ option of XCode and it seems, that there is no other appearance of OptionsTableViewController (except in comments) - I used the Edit -> Find -> Find in Project Feature to check on that. I also deleted the nib file as I don't use it.